# How to include performance goals in Java test suite?

Tags: java, performance, junit

Is there an easy way to automatically enforce goals like "This service must support 1,000 transactions per minute" in daily build tests for Java? Is this ever done in JUnit or are there caveats to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do exactly what you are looking for but you can do the below using [JUnitPerf](http://www.clarkware.com/software/JUnitPerf.html).

> JUnitPerf tests are intended to be
>   used specifically in situations where
>   you have quantitative performance
>   and/or scalability requirements that
>   you'd like to keep in check while
>   refactoring code. For example, you
>   might write a JUnitPerf test to ensure
>   that refactoring an algorithm didn't
>   incur undesirable performance overhead
>   in a performance-critical code
>   section. You might also write a
>   JUnitPerf test to ensure that
>   refactoring a resource pool didn't
>   adversely affect the scalability of
>   the pool under load.

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't feel like a unit test to me.  It could be a long-running transaction, one that will delay the completion of your build.  You might reconsider if the total running time is longer than your build frequency.

It's not even clear to me how meaningful the question is, because it doesn't take into account simultaneous users.

You can easily do a "poor man's" multi-threaded load test like this with TestNG.  It's not possible in JUnit 4.4, but it might be in a later version.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. Definitely not a Unit test. Just wondering if JUnit was capable of it. It would really easily integrate with the other tests that way.

Comment: Could be possible with JUnit 4.9 - I haven't done it, but I have with TestNG right out of the box.  http://junit.org/node/589 and http://testng.org/doc/index.html